# I am trying to write a method that will DETECT recursion in a file but am having trouble iterating through the methods of that file

Tags: java, oop, visitor-pattern

This is what my recursion detector looks like (with an error of "The method contains(String) is undefined for Method Declaration" in `if (md.contains(methodName))`). I am not sure how I should change this to make it work. I hope to have some advice on what I could do to iterate through each individual method and check for its methodName in it. Thank you!

RecursionDetector.java

```
package detectors;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.MethodDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.visitor.VoidVisitorAdapter;


public class RecursionDetector extends VoidVisitorAdapter <Breakpoints> {
    
    
    @Override
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration md, Breakpoints collector) {
        
        
        
        String className = getClass().getName();
        String methodName = md.getName().asString();
        int startline = md.getRange().get().begin.line;
        int endline = md.getRange().get().end.line;
        
        final StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        
        if (md.contains(methodName)) {
            
        }
        
        for (int i=0; i < trace.length-1; i++) {
            if( trace[i].equals(trace[trace.length-1]) ) {
                super.visit(md,  collector);
                collector.addEmpty(className, methodName, startline, endline);
            }
        }

    }
    

}
```

I also have a Breakpoints.java that looks like this:

```
package detectors;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Breakpoints {
    
    private ArrayList<String> collector = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Breakpoints() { }
    public void addClass(String currentClass) { }
    public void addMethod(String currentMethod) { }
    
    public ArrayList<String> returnCollector() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(this.collector);
    }
    
    public void addEmpty(String currentClass, String currentMethod, int startLine, int endLine) {
        String n = ("className: " + currentClass + ", methodName: " + currentMethod + ", startline : " + startLine
                + ", endline : " + endLine + "\n");
        if (collector.contains(n)) {
            return;
        }
        collector.add(n);
    }
    
}
```

And a Driver.java that looks like this:

```
package detectors;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.github.javaparser.*;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit;




public class Driver {

    public static String data;
    public static String data2 = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
             
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/Users/weihanng/Desktop/Calculator.java");
            
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);
              while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                data = myReader.nextLine();
                data2 = data2.concat(data);
              }

            myReader.close();
              
            CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(myFile);
            Breakpoints collector = new Breakpoints();
            
            cu.accept(new RecursionDetector(), collector); 
            System.out.println("Recursions: ");
            System.out.println(collector.returnCollector());

    
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the error message is clear enough - you're calling `.contains` on a `MethodDeclaration` object, which has no `contains` method.

Comment: @kaya3 yea but I'm not quite sure on how I could change my code to make it work